# Why does Python's != operator think that arguments are equal and not equal at the same time?

Tags: python

Take the following example:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def __init__(self, p):
...         self.p = p
...     def __eq__(self, o):
...         return True
... 
>>> C(1) is C(2)
False
>>> C(1) == C(2)
True
>>> C(1) != C(2)
True # <- Why?!?
```

So now the two objects are equal and not-equal at the same time. I though the two operations are opposing?!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python’s [“Data model”](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) explains it all:

> There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false. Accordingly, when defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the operators will behave as expected.

In `C(1) != C(2)`, it’s using the default implementation, where objects are equal only to themselves and unequal to everything else.

Defining `__cmp__` can be simpler, as it is used as a fallback for all comparison operations, not just some of them:

```
...   def __cmp__(self, o):
...     return 0
>>> C(1) != C(2)
False
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to just override ```__cmp__``` over ```__eq__```?

Comment: `__cmp__` is an older Python feature (`__eq__` takes precedence) and has now been removed from Python 3 so really shouldn't be used in any Python code now: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Comment: "That was true for Python 2, but in Python 3 that’s not good advice, because a useful default `__ne__` implementation is inherited from the object class, and it’s rarely necessary to override it." - Fluent Python

Answer (score 8):

There is a separate function for `!=` which is `__ne__` which is implicitly defined to compare the instance members.

What you want to do is:

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

or some variant of this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define both `__ne__` and `__eq__`. And you probably ought to consider implementing `__cmp__` too!