# I am having trouble understanding the __contains__ method in python

Tags: python, contains

I have set up a simple class called Cell

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, letter):
        self.letter = letter
        if letter == 'A' or letter == 'E' or letter == 'I' or letter == 'O' or letter == 'U' or letter == 'L' or letter == 'N' or letter == 'S' or  letter == 'T' or letter == 'R':
            self.points = 1
        elif letter == 'D' or letter == 'G':
            self.points = 2
        elif letter == 'B' or letter == 'C' or letter == 'M' or letter == 'P':
            self.points = 3
        elif letter == 'F' or letter == 'H' or letter == 'V' or letter == 'W' or letter == 'Y':
            self.points = 4
        elif letter == 'K':
            self.points = 5
        elif letter == 'J' or letter == 'X':
            self.points = 8
        elif letter == 'Q' or letter == 'Z':
            self.points = 10
        else:
            self.points = 0
```

And now I am trying to write a `__contains__` method for the class so if I have an array of Cells I can check if a Cell of some letter is contained in the array

```
Tiles = []
Tiles.append(Cell("A")
Tiles.append(Cell("B")
Tiles.append(Cell("C")
Tiles.append(Cell("D")
```

`Cell("A") in Tiles` should return `True`

However I am confused on how to go about doing this and have found little help online or in the python documentation

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to write a `__contains__` method for the class

No you're not. That's the question to ask when you're [implementing a container](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/sequence-types.html), not the thing being contained.

You're not confused about how to implement `__contains__` - you only implement that function on the *container*, which in this case is the list. You're interested on how contains works.

You need to implement `__eq__` (and `__hash__` and `__ne__`, for good measure)

I think this is expository:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, thing):
       self.thing = thing
    def __eq__(self, other):
       return other.thing == self.thing

a = [Cell(1)]
print Cell(1) in a
```

There are more complete examples here: [Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes)

I don't see a reference for how list contains works exactly, but a reference implementation is on [line 437 here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/listobject.c); basically it loops through the list and checks if the item provided is equal to any of the items in the list.

That's why we overload the '`==`' equality operator by overloading `__eq__`.

Naturally, this process is `O(n)` (takes time proportional to the number of items in the list - we have to check each one in the worst case). A dictionary or set can do this in `O(1)` "constant" time, but that requires hashing the input as a key. For this reason, it's typically customary to overload the hash function whenever you overload equality so that you don't get unexpected behaviour down the line. The `__ne__` is python's "not equals" operator. [Overload this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969629/why-does-pythons-operator-think-that-arguments-are-equal-and-not-equal-at-th)

Comment: Don't forget about `__ne__`, too.

Comment: A set is also a dictionary without the values and can look-up hashable values in constant time.

Comment: Thanks this is a very well laid out answer. My only question is why do I need to implement a `__hash__` function if I'm implementing `eq` and `ne`

Comment: @JamesNotaro for lists, you don't, but for any data structure that hashes its contents (like a dictionary or set), "Cell(1) in container" will be hash Cell(1), and check if that hash value is in the container. In that case, even if Cell(1) is *equal* to something in the structure, because its hash value doesn't match, you get that it isn't contained

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is a sequence, then `m in s` returns a `bool`. Now, `s` can also be *sequence-like* when the class `type(s)` implements the `__contains__` method.

Hence `obj in Tiles` has nothing to do with membership in `obj` but in list `Tiles`.

Secondly, why `Cell('A') in Tiles` returned `False` after appending one before? Because they are **different** objects. You could introduce new semantics stating they being same when such and such satisfies, by implementing the `__eq__` method.

```
x = Cell('A')
y = Cell('A')
x is y # False, same as id(x) == id(y)
x == y # don't really know what that means
# now enriching semantics by __eq__
x == y # True/ False
```

If you want to use those objects as keys, the `__hash__` function should be implemented. But there are caveats. Check the docs.