# XSLT equal and not equal operators returns same result for absent node. How is it possible?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

XML:

```
<root></root>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        absent_node EQUALS zero-length string [<xsl:value-of select="absent_node=''"/>];
        absent_node NOT EQUALS zero-length string via != [<xsl:value-of select="absent_node!=''"/>]
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
absent_node EQUALS zero-length string [false];
absent_node NOT EQUALS zero-length string [false]
```

I saw [similar issue with python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969675/4633770) but need an explanation here.

Is using not() preferred if I want to get just opposite result without explicit value type casting via text() or string()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the expected result in this type of comparison.

You are comparing a node-set to a string. The [rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans) for such comparison state that:

> the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the
>   node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the
>   string-value of the node and the other string is true.

This rule is defined uniformly for all comparison operators (`=, !=, <=, <, >= and >`).

Since your node-set is empty, there will never be a node in it for which the comparison returns true - no matter which operator you use.

---

It is customary to use:

```
not(node = 'string')
```

as the negation of:

```
node = 'string'
```

Comment: The quote is from the XPath 1.0 spec, but the 2.0 rules are essentially the same, though generalized to arbitrary sequences. When X is an empty sequence, then (X = 'a') means "there is an item in X that is equal to 'a'", while (X != 'a') means  "there is an item in X that is not equal to 'a'"; both conditions are false if X is an empty sequence.

Comment: Incidentally, note that if you treat an absent element/attribute as being like null in SQL, then the semantics are very similar to the SQL semantics: X='a' and X!='a' when used in predicates both cause X not to be selected.  The difference is that in SQL, the predicate effectively evaluates to null, whereas in XPath it evaluates to false.